# Pygame module recognises clicks while the program is paused with pygame.time.delay(x)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently learning to program my first Python games with the module "pygame". I've already programmed a Spaceship shooter game with the help of a video tutorial and now I'm programming a Tic-Tac-Toe game all by myself. I already managed to do that and what I'm now trying to do is to add two different game modi (player vs. player / player vs. AI). But that's not what I'm having problems. When the code detects that someone has won (or it's a tie), a win message is being displayed and I'm using `pygame.time.delay(2000)` to show that message for 2 seconds before the next round begins. But when I click somewhere during that time, as soon as the message disappears and the next round starts, a mark is set at the place I clicked.
I already tried to not only reset the board at the end of the round, but also in the beginning of the next round, but that didn't change anything

```
def main():
    global current_player, cross_score, circle_score, game_started, game_mode

    reset_cells()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                quit()

            for rectangle in RECTANGLES:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:          # checking for left mouse-button
                    clicked = bool(rectangle.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()))
                    if clicked:
                        for cell in CELLS:
                            if cell.x == rectangle.x and cell.y == rectangle.y and cell.content == '' and game_started:
                                if game_mode == 'ai' and current_player == 'Cross' or game_mode == 'multiplayer':
                                    cell.content = current_player
                                    current_player = 'Circle' if current_player == 'Cross' else 'Cross'
                                    print(cell.x, cell.y)

            if not game_started and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:    # checking if a button on the title screen has been pressed
                clicked_multiplayer = bool(TITLE_BUTTON_MULTIPLAYER_BORDER.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()))
                clicked_ai = bool(TITLE_BUTTON_AI_BORDER.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()))

                if clicked_multiplayer:
                    game_mode, game_started = 'multiplayer', True
                elif clicked_ai:
                    game_mode, game_started = 'ai', True

            if game_started and event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                game_started = False
                game_mode = None
                reset_cells()
                cross_score, circle_score = 0, 0

            if game_started and game_mode == 'ai' and current_player == 'Circle' and win_check()[0] == '':
                cell = get_computer_move()
                cell.content = 'Circle'
                current_player = 'Cross'

        winner = win_check()
        win_text = ''
        if winner[0] == 'Cross':
            win_text = 'Cross wins!'
            cross_score += 1
        elif winner[0] == 'Circle':
            win_text = 'Circle wins!'
            circle_score += 1
        elif winner[0] == 'Tie':
            win_text = "It's a tie!"
            draw_window(game_started)
            draw_winner(win_text)
            break

        if win_text != '':
            draw_window(game_started)
            try:                           
                pygame.draw.rect(WIN, RED, get_win_indicating_line(winner[1]))
            except TypeError:
                WIN.blit(get_win_indicating_line(winner[1]), (0, 0))
            draw_winner(win_text)
            break

        draw_window(game_started)

    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `pygame.time.delay(2000)` events are still stored in the event queue, which is then used and emptied by `pygame.event.get()`.
In order to ignore any events happening during the 2 seconds you can just call `pygame.event.get()` directly after the 2 s delay. I would recommend to still check if a `pygame.QUIT` event is in this `pygame.event.get()` because this event would be discarded as well.